# Sentence pattern for asking "should I do A or B?"

Tags: grammar, modality

We commonly encounter situations when there are a number of options and we would like to ask for instructions as to which option to choose. Here is a real example from my recent experience. I was trying to fill in a form but was not sure what to write in a box. I then asked

> この欄に、携帯番号を記入しますか？それとも、空白にしますか？

In English, the direct translation would be

> In this box, will I write my mobile number? Or, will I leave it blank?

But what I really wanted ask was

> In this box, **should** I write my mobile number? Or, **should** I leave it blank?

In situations like the above, what sentence pattern in Japanese should I use?

Perhaps *sentence patterns* are not exactly the right thing to ask for. I think I might be digging into *modality* here, and would be grateful if someone could elaborate on this.

Answer (score 1):

verb(plain form) + ”べき”

In your example, ”この欄に携帯番号を記入するべきですか？それとも、空白にするべきですか？”.

Example
記入する + べき = 記入するべき(I should write)
食べる + べき = 食べるべき(I should eat)